# JavaFX application won't compile in NetBeans IDE 8.1

Tags: javafx

I am trying to run this application in which I used event-handling and it won't compile and won't show anything. I am currently using NetBeans 8.1. What is that I did wrong. Also it is not showing any errors.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class event extends Application {


public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
   HBox pane = new HBox();
   pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
   Button btOk = new Button("OK");
   Button btCancel = new Button("Cancel");
   OkHandlerClass handler1 = new OkHandlerClass();
   btOk.setOnAction(handler1);
   CancelHandlerClass handler2 = new CancelHandlerClass();
   pane.getChildren().addAll(btOk, btCancel);

   Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
   primaryStage.setTitle("Handle the fucking event");
   primaryStage.setScene(scene);
   primaryStage.show();
 }

 class OkHandlerClass implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("OK button clicked");
    }
 }
 class CancelHandlerClass implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{


    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
       System.out.println("Cancel button clicked");
    }


 }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
 }



 }
```

Comment: In NetBeans it doesnt.

Comment: It doesn't show any error,just it doesnt compile at all @pzaenger

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesnt compile at all_?

Comment: ant -f C:\\Users\\Planet\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ELIS -Djavac.includes=elis/ELIS.java -Dnb.internal.action.name=run.single -Drun.class=elis.ELIS run-single
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\Planet\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ELIS\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Planet\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ELIS\build\built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Planet\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ELIS\build\classes
compile-single:
run-single:

Comment: THIS IS THE OUTPUT @pzaenger